# A set of eight tiles can be arranged to form the word SATURDAY. How many three-letter “words” can be formed with these tiles if no tile is repeat.

Tags: combinatorics

a) A set of eight tiles can be arranged to form the word SATURDAY. How many three-letter “words” can be formed with these tiles if no tile is to be used more than once?

I did $8\cdot 7\cdot 6$ but realised that's wrong because of the double counting. How do I account for double counting?

b) How many nine-letter words can be formed from the letters of PARRAMATTA? How many eight-letter words?

I know how to do 10 letter words from that i.e. $\frac {10!}{4!2!2!}$. But I'm lost on $9$ and $8$ letter words.

Please consider including short justifications for your answer and/or why what I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: For the first, note there are $7$ distinct letters. Count separately no repeated letter words, there are $(7)(6)(5)$,  and words with $2$ A's, there are  $(3)(6)$.

Comment: How did you get 'words with 2 A's, there are (3)(6)' ?

Comment: Choose the position for the letter that's not A, then choose what that letter is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a), you can account for double-counting by subtracting the number of words with 2 A's and the number of words with 1 A, since you have counted these twice.
There are $3\cdot6$ words with 2 A's, and $\binom{6}{2}\cdot3!$ words with 1 A, so this gives $8\cdot7\cdot6-3\cdot6-15\cdot6=228$ words.  (Of course, the method of direct counting described by Andre Nicolas is easier.)

For b), you can count the 9-letter words using the fact that any 9-letter word corresponds to a unique 10-letter word by inserting the missing letter at the end.

For 8-letter words, try breaking it into cases based on the number of A's in the word:

1) If there are 2 A's, then you have the letters AAPRRMTT to arrange.

2) If there are 3 A's, then you can break this into subcases based on the letter
that is omitted.  (The cases P and M should have similar counts, as should the cases R and T.)

3) If there are 4 A's, then you break this into subcases based on the 2 letters omitted:  RR, TT, PR, PM, PT, MR, MT.

Comment: thanks, figured 9-letter word but stuck on 8 letter words